# Hogwarts parchment length compared to standard paper?

Tags: harry-potter

We read that the students are writing foot-long essays, and sometimes up to 2-3 feet of parchment in essays. Do we have a way to compare this to a normal school using regular paper or type? How long is a 3 foot essay on werewolves really for us Muggles?

Comment: `How long is a 3 foot essay on werewolves really?` - 3 feet.

Comment: I'd've thought it's more the width that's interesting, or would you like to know how long a 'roll' of parchment is. Three feet is actually quite short, really, if parchment is as wide as A4. Three feet, as you probably know, is about three sides of A4, actually a little more

Comment: A4 (297mm = 11.69") and Letter (11") are pretty close to 1 foot vertically.  A 3-foot essay in Hogwarts is a 3-page essay in the real world.

Comment: As I recall, there was a time when Harry and Ron were trying to write as big as possible so they could finish in less lines. Which reminds me of in school when there was a maximum font size for essays. Since no font size was specified in the books, and it might've varied from class to class, I doubt there's going to be a complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

A4 paper is 11.69 inches long. That means that a "3 foot" essay would be just over 3 pages of A4 or roughly 1200 words, assuming an average writing size.